# wordpress basics newbie here

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$points = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT points FROM wp_watu_takings WHERE user_id = 'idontknowwhattoputhere'");
echo "<p> {$points} </p>";

?>
```

I am trying to show a specific values from my database. I know this is very basic but i forgot how to do it. can someone please help me.
I am new to wordpress same with codings in php.

I want to get the current user who is logged in and display his/her points from the quiz/exam, but i don't know what to put after `WHERE user_id =`

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials and guides out there, SO is neither.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to start reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples  Your answer is covered in the docs.

Comment: This question is properly worded, includes a code example and is asked politely. Just because it's basic doesn't mean it should be voted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$points = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT points FROM wp_watu_takings WHERE user_id = " .   $current_user->ID . ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

get_var("SELECT points FROM wp_watu_takings WHERE user_id = '".$current_user_id."'");
echo "

{$points}

";

?>

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you need to use [PHP's concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) `.` to combine your text string with the variables you have created. That code looks like this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$points = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT points FROM wp_watu_takings WHERE user_id =' . $current_user . '");
echo '<p>' . $points . '</p>';
```

But the way you are doing this query using `$wpdb` isn't how I like to get data in WP. It's much better to use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query), which are performant and will help teach you better syntax. Yes, using WP_Query right here is probably overkill for such as simple request but it is a good practice if you are just learning.

How you might go about doing this with WP_User_Query:

```
  // 1- Gets the current user
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  // 2- Setups WP_Query to find points user got on their exam
  $args = array(
    'search' => $current_user
    'post_type' => 'wp_watu_takings'
  );
  $the_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

  // 3- Output result after checking for presence of data
  if($the_query->have_posts()) {
    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
      $the_query->the_post();

      echo the_field('points');
    }
  }
```

Comment: If this answered your question, try and mark my answer as the right one you selected. That's how you establish cred around the site.